# extracting values from an array of nested objects without duplicates

Tags: javascript, performance, array

I have my solution for the below usecase but I would like to know whether is any other effective solution for the same.

**My Data:**

```js
const myArr = [{
  data: {
    studyUId: 'abc',
    seriesData: [ { seriesUId: "123", modality: "VX"}, { seriesUId: "ef3", modality: "GX"} ]
  }
},
{
  data: {
    studyUId: 'fgh',
    seriesData: [ { seriesUId: "grhg", modality: "VX"}, { seriesUId: "dter", modality: "GX"}, { seriesUId: "tg3", modality: "YX"} ]
  }
},
{
  data: {
    studyUId: 'tyb',
    seriesData: [ { seriesUId: "753", modality: "YX"}]
  }
 },
{
  data: {
    studyUId: 'fgh',
    seriesData: [ { seriesUId: "grhg", modality: "VX"}, { seriesUId: "tg3", modality: "YX"} ]
  }
}];
```

**My Expected Outputs:**

```
// All the values of `studyUId` without duplicates as an array
[ 'abc', 'fgh', 'tyb']
```

```
// All the values of `seriesUId` without duplicates as an array
[ '123', 'ef3', 'grhg', 'dter', 'tg3', '753']
```

**My Solution:**

```js
const studyArr = [...new Set(myArr.map(el => el.data.studyUId ))];
console.log(studyArr);

const seriesArr = [...new Set(
                     myArr.map(el => 
                        el.data.seriesData.map(series => series.seriesUId)
                     ).flat()
                  )];
console.log(seriesArr);
```

Although I have the solution, I am not sure whether it's the best way to do this!

Is there any better way to improve the solution to make it more efficient in terms of speed & code efficiency?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not much to improve other than to use [`array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) on that second one.

Comment: Thank you @Joseph